# How do I call a function with arbitrary parameters from another function?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'd like to know how I would go about doing something like this (in python 2):

```
def myFunction(fn, params):
    return ("You called " + fn.__name__ + "(" + str(params) ")" + 
        " and got " + str(fn(params)))
```

Say I have a couple functions:

```
def doSomething(s):
    # manipulation
    return s

def doAnotherThing(someInt, someOtherInt, someString):
    # do something with them
    return someValue
```

I'd like to be able to call `myFunction(doSomething, "hello")`, and get `You called doSomething("hello") and got "something"`. This approach seems to work for functions that take a single input, but I can't get it to work for functions that take multiple inputs, e.g. calling `myFunction(doAnotherThing, (myInt, myOtherInt, myString))`. I think I need to do something involving `*` and `**` so that I can take the keywords arbitrarily instead of as a `tuple`, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: You're looking for a [decorator](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/), I recommend reading up on them to do what you want properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, all you need to do is add a `*` in front of the tuple (or `**` in front of a dict for keyword arguments) when calling the interior function. This is called [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
def wrapper(fn, params, keyword_params):
    return fn(*params, **keyword_params)

def myfunc(a, b, c=0):
    return (a + b)/c

wrapper(myfunc, (2, 5), {'c': 3})
```

You can also use [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) to potentially simplify the wrapper function. This will allow you to automatically package additional arguments to feed to interior functions without having to pre-package them in tuples and dictionaries.

```
def wrapper(fn, *params, **keyword_params):  # Note the asterisks
    return fn(*params, **keyword_params)

def myfunc(a, b, c=1):
    return (a + b)/c

wrapper(myfunc, 2, 5, c=3)  # Nicer function call
```

---

Note that just using the first method will actually break single-argument implementations, as the `*` operator expects an iterator to unpack. So you have to either always pre-package the arguments or add some type-checking in the `wrapper` function.

```
def wrapper(fn, params):
    return fn(*params)

def myfunc(a):
    return 2*a

wrapper(myfunc, 2)
# TypeError: myfunc() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

wrapper(myfunc, (2,))  # Package the argument in a single-element tuple
# 4
```

The second method doesn't have this problem.

Comment: You could also include the `*`s in the definition of `wrapper`, so that its call looks just like the nested one:`def wrapper(fn, *params, **keyword_params)`, and then you can call `wrapper(myfunc, 2, 5, c=3)`.

Comment: @RogerFan Might also want to explicitly add the printing stuff to your `wrapper` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
def myFunction(fn, *params):
    return ("You called " + fn.__name__ + str(params) +
        " and got " + str(fn(*params)))

import math
print myFunction(math.sqrt, 4)

print myFunction(open, '/etc/passwd', 'r')
print myFunction(lambda x: x+1, 41)
```

Result:

```
You called sqrt(4,) and got 2.0
You called open('/etc/passwd', 'r') and got <open file '/etc/passwd', mode 'r' at 0x7f20e9cb65d0>
You called <lambda>(41,) and got 42
```